# Is it possible to have multiple parameters within a Report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a parameter called Reporting Level in my Report  where you can choose from 4 options:

Company
BDM
Region
Site

What I want to be able to do is this:

Select BDM and this opens another Parameter call BDM List (This is based on Get Values from a query), but I want the other Parameters to stay greyed out. Once a selection is made from the BDM List then the Time and Date Parameter becomes available.

Is this possible?

These are my Datasets for the BDM List and Region List:

```
    SELECT SiteInfo FROM
    ((SELECT DISTINCT BDM, Region, SiteName As SiteInfo 
    FROM Site 
    WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'BDM' 
    union all
    SELECT DISTINCT BDM, Region, SiteName As SiteInfo 
    FROM Site 
    WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'Region' ) 
    union all
    SELECT DISTINCT BDM, Region, SiteName As SiteInfo 
    FROM Site
    WHERE @ReportingLevel = 'SiteName') AS QRY2
```

This is my main Dataset:

```
    SELECT       OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth, SUM(OccupancyDetail.No_of_Nights) AS No_of_Nights, 
                         SUM(OccupancyDetail.Capacity) AS Capacity
FROM            OccupancyDetail INNER JOIN
                         Site ON OccupancyDetail.Site_Skey = Site.Site_Skey

WHERE  (OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate = convert(Date,getdate()))
AND CASE WHEN @Time = 'YEAR' THEN CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) else CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) end in (@Dates)
AND Site.BDM IN (@BDM)
AND Site.Region IN (@Region)
AND Site.SiteName IN (@SiteName)


GROUP BY OccupancyDetail.ReferenceDate, OccupancyDetail.CalendarYear, OccupancyDetail.CalendarMonth
```

Time Dataset

```
select DateChoice FROM
(select distinct CalendarYear, 1 as MonthNumber,CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice from Time
where @Time = 'YEAR'


union all

select Distinct CalendarYear, MonthNumber,CalendarMonth + ' ' + CAST(CalendarYear as varchar(4)) as DateChoice from Time where @Time = 'MONTH') as QRYDATA
ORDER BY CalendarYear,MonthNumber
```

I hope you can help this is my 3rd day working on this.

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: I don't think I do, I have amended the above information can you have a look at tell me what I need to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the last link shows a very good step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to use cascading parameters, here are a few links that should help you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx

http://thevirtualzoneblog.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/creating-cascading-parameter-reports-using-sql-server-reporting-services-v2008/

With the first link, go to the section marked 'To create a dataset to provide values for a dependent parameter'. This next one shows the parameters as greyed out before the parent has an option selected:

http://www.resultdata.com/adding-cascading-parameters-to-a-ssrs-report/

---

### Update

I have found a video tutorial for you:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAYGupJcHkU

Comment: Thanks twoleggedhorse, but those links talk about stored procedures and I haven't stating learning about them yet. Ta

Comment: @wafw1971 I have updated my answer for you with a video example

Comment: @wafw1971 Has this question been answered or are you still having trouble?

Comment: Hi Twoleggedhorse

All sorted now

Thanks